# Drivers for Asus K Series K555LN-XO079D?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, laptop, asus

I want to buy Asus K555LN but I wonder whether I can find drivers for Ubuntu? The Asus web site even does not list drivers for Windows. May be I don't need to install any drivers at all?